# How to manually set K-means cluster's centers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I would like to not to predic centers, but to assign each object to an already defined center. How can I?

Comment: Do you mean you want to manually select each cluster "center" and categorize each point to the closest "center"?

Comment: Yes Phillip, I maybe looking into wrong method. Newbie here...

Comment: I don't know if scikit-learn does this or not, but you can implement this yourself fairly easily. Pick your centers manually, for every point calculate the distance from each center, choose the closest center for each point, and now you've categorized.

Comment: See my answer here for implementation in python: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412601/equal-distribution-of-points-to-regional-hubs-in-qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to take a look at the KMeans implementation in [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html). The parameter `minit` accepts a matrix and

> interpret[s] the k parameter as a k by M (or length k array for one-dimensional data) array of initial centroids.

Answer (score 2):

You can `fit` your KMeans to the desired cluster centers, and then use this model to predict your data.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

cluster_centers = np.array([[1, 1], [0, 0]])
data  = [[1, 2], [1, 1], [3, 1], [10, -1]]

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=cluster_centers, n_init=1)
kmeans.fit(cluster_centers)
```

We just fit the model with our two desired center points, making our desired cluster centers the actual centers of the model.

```
kmeans.cluster_centers_
# array([[0., 0.],
#        [1., 1.]])
kmeans.predict(data)
# array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

If we use this model to assign the data, all data points are assigned to cluster 1.

In contrast, if we initiate on our cluster centers and then fit the model to the data, the centers get adjusted and are no longer the ones we initially wanted.

```
kmeans_init = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=cluster_centers, n_init=1)
kmeans_init.fit(data)
kmeans_init.cluster_centers_
# array([[ 1.66666667,  1.33333333],
#        [10.        , -1.        ]])
kmeans_init.predict(data)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Now the data is spread over the two clusters.

Note: `n_clusters` has to match the number of your cluster centers

Comment: Other answers tell you how to set the initial centroids/cluster centers. However those will get overwritten when fitting the data, unless the data matches exactly the centroids.

Comment: `kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init=cluster_centers, n_init=1)` to make sure the center ordering are the same.

Comment: the variable init (centers you want) must be instanced in KMeans instance

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an array( let's call it X) containing your desired centers and in the kmean algorithm put 'init= X'
take a look at the following example from sklearn:

```
class sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, *, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, algorithm='auto')

>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
>>> kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
>>> kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
>>> kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

for more information :
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the `n_init` and `random_state` parameters of the `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` module, like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

c = KMeans(n_init=1, random_state=1)
```

This does two things:
1) `random_state=1` sets the centroid seed(s) to 1. This isn't exactly the same thing as specifically selecting the coordinates of the centroid you want, but it does allow you to control and reproduce the seed.

2) `n_init=1` sets the number of iterations to 1, which means that you will limit the cluster attempt to only that seed which you select yourself in the `random_state` step.

You can additionally select the number of centroids you want created by using the `n_clusters` parameter.

From here, fitting and predicting will allocate points to the different clusters you have pre-established.

Comment: But this does not give us control on where exactly to place the centroids at... right ? which is not of much use in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn has a `is_fitted()` check before you do predictions. So, you can fit the model using dummy data. Then you can force the cluster centroids using the KMeans instance's `cluster_centers_` parameter as follows:

```
kmeans.cluster_centers_ = np.array([[218,173,63],
                                    [146,122,50],
                                    [69,77,36]]).astype(np.float64)
```